# MySQL LEFT JOIN is causing "duplicate" rows

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have tables "customers" and "plans" and I want to list all customers regardless they have a plan or not. I'm using query to do it

```
SELECT customer.name, plan.goal
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN plan ON plan.customerid=customer.customerid
ORDER BY customer.name
```

I also want to see the goal (plan.goal) with the customer name. This works as long as customer does not have a plan or has a single plan. If customer has two or more plans then I get as many rows of customer name as there are plans.

What I want is customer.name and plan.goal from the latest plan. We can assume the higher value in plan.planid is the latest plan.

I guess I should use sub queries and INNER JOINS some how but I just don't get it right now...

Comment: how are you defining the "latest plan" is there a datetime or preferably an auto incrementing ID on the table?

Comment: plan.planid is auto incremented

Comment: You need to use multiple queries, your first paragraph contradicts your second and third.

Comment: I want to list all customers regardless how many plans they have (0-n). I also want the plan.goal from the latest plan if it exists. No contradiction there IMO

Comment: You want to list all customers, but you want to list the same customer multiple times if has multiple plans. That will be difficult to achieve.

Comment: No, I want to list the customer once and goal once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think something like this would work:

```
SELECT customer.name, plan.goal
FROM customer c
inner join plan p on c.customerId = p.customerId
inner JOIN (
    -- grabs the most recent plan per customer
    select max(planId) as planId, customerId
    from plan
    group by customerId
) maxPlan on p.planId = maxPlan.planId
UNION
-- handles customers w/o a plan
select customer.name, null
from customer c
left join plan p on c.customerId = p.customerId
where p.customerId is null
ORDER BY customer.name
```

Comment: The above does not list a customer if customer does not have a plan.

Comment: It works except the ORDER BY clause is not working: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.name' in 'order clause' and same result for customer.name also

Comment: I figured that out myself. I added a couple more joins and now the monster is ready.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT c.name, 
( SELECT p.goal
  FROM plan p
  WHERE p.customerid=c.customerid
  AND NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                    FROM plan p2
                    WHERE p2.customerid = p.customerid
                    AND p2.planid > p.planId
                  )
)
FROM customer c
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a boolean/tinyint column to the plan table that says `IsLatest` or something like that.  Then you could do:

```
SELECT customer.name, plan.goal
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN plan ON plan.customerid=customer.customerid
where testplan.islatest = 1 or testplan.islatest is null
ORDER BY customer.name
```

Also, I would stay away from the sub-query answers such as

```
select a from (select b from c where e=f) where g=h
```

as they don't often perform very well, besides being confusing to read.

Comment: It is cleaner and it lists all customers but it does not list goals from latest plans if there are multiple plans per customer.

Comment: You're sure right.  My mistake.  I think you should add a column to the plan table that says `isactive` or `islatest` or something like that.  A little extra data to store but it makes this situation much easier as you can then add that to a where clause and avoid complex/sub/nested queries.

Comment: I edited my answer to use the new column approach, as I think it is the best solution

Comment: You are right about that. Now I need to perform complex queries to find the latest goal. On the other hand I need to run queries to mark old plans not active any more.